# running shellcode + vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, shellcode

I just tried the following code snippet for shellcode testing purposes:-

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

char sc[] = ""; #i've removed the shellcode
int main() {
    int (*func)();
    func = (int(*)())sc;
    (int)(*func)();
}
```

I get a build error  on compilation :-

```
------ Build started: Project: shellcoderunner, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Build started 10/15/2011 12:51:16 PM.
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "Debug\shellcoderunner.unsuccessfulbuild".
ClCompile:
  blah.cpp
c:\users\reverser\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\shellcoderunner\shellcoderunner\blah.cpp(7): error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'char [149]' to 'int (__cdecl *)(void)'
          There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Build FAILED.

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.99
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a shellcode in your C/C++ program with VS, the simplest way is embedding an Assembly code like this example below:

```
char* buffer="blah blah blah";
int main() {
    __asm{
        lea eax, buffer
        call    eax
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Access violationg executing location

Answer (score 1):

[
At the time I am answering the question is about why compilation fails for …

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

char sc[] = ""; #i've removed the shellcode
int main() {
    int (*func)();
    func = (int(*)())sc;
    (int)(*func)();
}
```

This code is an attempt to execute data bytes as machine code. However, the OP calls this a “code snippet for shellcode testing purposes”, which is unrelated. And so I am including this original context.
]

You may have success using a `void*` as intermediary.

In the formal even that should not compile, because in the formal a data pointer cannot be converted to a function pointer or vice versa.

However, reportedly Posix requires the ability to do that conversion, and it's old existing practice, so I believe most if not all compilers support it.

Note that you are in UB-land as regarding effects.

Also, note that anti-virus software and page level execute permission checking may disagree a bit with trying to execute the bytes in a string as machine code, so at that higher level yes you're doing something obviously wrong. ;-)

By the way, if what you are trying to achieve is to execute a shell script, then look into the `system` function.

What command to pass in the `system` call would depend on your system, so if you change your question be sure to include information about that.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: thanks but no, im not trying to execute a shellscript. I meant "opcodes" like "\x90\x90\x90" and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work:

```
char sc[] = ""; // i've removed the shellcode

int main()
{
    int (*func)() = (int(*)())sc;   // C++
    int (*func)() = sc;             /* C  */
    func();
}
```

It's technically undefined behaviour, but then again that's the whole point of shellcode.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast an array to a function pointer. You have to first acquire a pointer to the array, which then can be cast:

```
func = (int(*)())&sc;
```