# Contextual differences in inline assembly code

Tags: c++, inline-assembly

Along the lines with the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776451/running-shellcode-vs2010) I tried to encapsulate some assembly code in a C++ function.

When I put this code in a function (inline or not) and pass the shellcode as an argument to the function it gives me an access violation 0xC0000005 at the `call` instruction, with or without DEP enabled. However, when I define the shellcode inside the function just before VirtualProtect, it works fine.

Current function code:

```
inline void ExecuteShellcode(char shellcode[])
{
    /*char shellcode[] = \
    "shellcode"; // If I use this local variable instead of the argument it works tho
    */
    DWORD tempstore;
    if (VirtualProtect(shellcode, sizeof(shellcode), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &tempstore))
    {
        __asm lea eax, shellcode;
        __asm call eax; Access violation 0xC0000005
    }
}
```

Why does `__asm call` not work with non-local variables in this instance?

Comment: `sizeof(shellcode)` is probably 1

Comment: tkausl: `sizeof(shellcode)` is 4.. Which is way too small.
Michael: When I look in the debugger the globally allocated pointer contains the same value as the one passed to `VirtualProtect`

Comment: The reason is that inside the function the compiler doesn't know the length of the character array passed as a parameter. `sizeof(shellcode)` would be the size of a pointer to the character array. When `shellcode` is a local variable the size is known.

Comment: Michael: Is there any way around this?

Comment: Pass the size as a separate parameter to the function `ExecuteShellCode`

Comment: I should point out that had you defined the string as `char *shellcode="Hello World";` and done sizeof(shellcode) you would have also got 4 (the size of the pointer). This [SO Question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c) touch on the subject.